# Service, потоки и JSON

Tags: android, json, android-service

Как все должно быть.

В Service, в отдельном потоке, каждые 2-3+ секунд выполняется запрос JSON-данных, получая некую информацию - которой дополняем, например, строку. Что-то вроде лога. Строку также можно сохранять в SharedPreferences при завершеннии приложения.

Эта строка должна передаваться в TextView активити, которая может быть закрыта (так как сервис в бэкграунде). Но как только пользователь, например, получил Notification "У вас посетитель!", щелкнул и открыл эту активити - информация в TextView должна обновиться. И с каждым получением данных, прямо на экране она должна обновляться в реальном времени.

Над чем я думаю:

1. Сервис вроде сам по себе не отдельный поток. Значит, надо либо создать в нем поток, либо использовать в нем AsyncTask, запуская таск каждый раз заново. Как лучше поступить, как реализовать цикл с постоянным запросом JSON?
2. Обращение к элементам главного потока. Мне надо будет менять содержимое TextView, но насколько я помню, к элементам нельзя обращаться из другого потока. Вроде бы для этого и используют AsyncTask. Но в моем предыдущем вопросе человек посоветовал использовать ивенты.

В общем я запутался :)

Comment: Направление у вас в общем правильное. Начните делать сервис и задавайте конкретные вопросы. Единственное, что скажу сразу, забудьте про AsyncTask в сервисе. Не ждите, что кто-то вам тут всю архитектуру распишет :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Думаю - использовать ли поток внутри сервиса, или IntentService? Погуглил, народ не шибко жалует цикл while в последнем, так как IntentService имеет задачу выполнить входящие Intents очередью и завершить выполнение.

Comment: Так либо сервис, либо IntentService, тут уж определитесь.

Comment: Ну как я понял, IntentService - унаследован от Сервиса. Предназначение у него - запуститься в другом потоке, получить на вход очередью задачи и выполнить их. В инете пишут, что вроде бы он лучше подходит для долгих задач. Читал тут. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice. Однако, у меня нет очереди задач. Возможно мне стоит просто вызывать поток из Service?

Comment: "каждые 2-3+ секунд выполняется запрос JSON-данных" -- чем не очередь задач? Пусть и однотипных. Рекоммендую дополнительно прочесть: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja по поводу очереди задач. По поводу ваших слов у меня два варианта: 1) В главном потоке запустить цикл с паузами, который будет через каждые 3 секунды вызывать IntentService. Насколько я понимаю, после выполнения задачи он закрывается, так что он будет постоянно открываться и закрываться. Кажется что-то не то.  2) Непрерывно слать запросы в IntentService, внутри которого уже будет пауза. Ну это я уже бред какой-то говорю.

Comment: Полагаю, если вызвать поток из простого Service, то это будет отдельный поток, а не Service и система его в итоге закроет.

Comment: Забудьте про блокировку UI потока, вообще, совсем ("от слова никогда"). Переход между потоками тоже не простая операция, скакать между ними, надо как можно меньше. Дополню свой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервисы бывают разные, есть те что изначально работают в бэкграунде, есть те что работают в UI потоке (для них надо запускать другой поток). Опять же, последние платформы андроида, будут убивать обычный сервис вместе с Активит, что бы этого не происходило надо стартовать foreground service, в бэграунде ходить за инфой сохранять ее где-то и к примеру кидать event что инфа изменилась (предварительно в бэкграунд потоке можно сравнивать изменение инфы). Как я говорил раньше, можно использовать RxJava или EventBus (проще разобраться в EventBus'e).

UPD: Если сервер не шлет данные, а Вы сами за ними ходите можно сделать так: Создать Service или Foreground service (если рассчитываете поддерживать последние версии андроида, но он немного сложнее обычного, надо еще создать Notification для его запуска), открываете НОВЫЙ поток в котором ходите на сервер (хорошо подумайте над частотой запросов, если у вас обновляются какие-то курсы валют или акции это одно дело и то не 2-3 секунды, а если более менее "стабильная" информация, обновляйте как можно реже, т.к. запросы жрут трафик и очень садят батарейку, так что тут ищите золотую середину) и не закрываете этот поток пока живет сервис. То есть, получение информации идет в бэкграунд потоке, дальше кидаете ивенты из Бэкграунд потока, а принимаете его уже в UI потоке (EventBus и RxJava легко с этим справляется) и обновляете нужную view.

Comment: Благодарю, про EventBus читал сегодня, но пока застрял с сервисом. "Android Architecture Components" пока меня вгоняет в ступор, хотя вначале более-менее понятно. Про сервис в обсуждении под вопросом написал вопрос.